# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable(Pygame)

Tags: python, int, pygame, python-3.2, callable

I am attempting to make a floor that loads at the bottom of the screen for little platformer. I am doing it the this way also so later on it will be easier(I think) to have the floor load only in the camera versus loading infinitely. I did try to find a solution but I am not mentioning "N" as a function so I have no idea. Any help or general suggestions are appreciated. And yes I know that there are some useless things in there right now but I just have yet to get around to them yet( FPS, BASICFONT)

```
def drawTiles():
    N = 0
    while (N < tilesNeeded):
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, GREEN, (20(N), floorx, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, LIGHTGREEN, ((TILESIZE/4) + (20(N)), (floorx + (TILESIZE/4)), TILESIZE / 2, TILESIZE / 2))
        N = N + 1
```

Here is the whole program to look at

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *

TILESIZE = 20
WINDOWWIDTH = 640
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480
FPS = 30
floorx = (WINDOWHEIGHT - (TILESIZE))
floory = (WINDOWWIDTH / TILESIZE)
TileOffset = 20
tilesNeeded = (WINDOWWIDTH / TILESIZE)



BLACK =         (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE =         (255, 255, 255)
SKYBLUE =       (200, 210, 255)
DARKTURQUOISE = (  3,  54,  73)
GREEN =         (  0,  92,   7)
LIGHTGREEN =    (  0, 135,  15)


def main():
    global FPSCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF, BASICFONT, TILESIZE, floorx, floory, floorCovered, tilesNeeded

    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Alpha One')

    DISPLAYSURF.fill(SKYBLUE)

    drawTiles()



    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        pygame.display.update()

def drawTiles():
    N = 0
    while (N < tilesNeeded):
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, GREEN, (20(N), floorx, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, LIGHTGREEN, ((TILESIZE/4) + (20(N)), (floorx + (TILESIZE/4)), TILESIZE / 2, TILESIZE / 2))
        N = N + 1





if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, GREEN, (20(N), floorx, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
```

In particular `20(N)` to Python looks like you're calling the object 20 with an argument of N. but 20 is an integer which is not callable, so it throws the exception.

Do you mean `20*N`?

Btw, more pythonic is to write `while (N < tilesNeeded):` as `for N in range(tilesNeeded):` and then you don't need to explicitly increment it.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Changing it to the multiplication sign fixed. Will definitely have to remember that for later. Thanks again!